# How find the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\binom{4n-4}{n-1}}{2^{4n-3}(3n-2)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, constants

today,I see a amazing math problem:

show that

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\binom{4n-4}{n-1}}{2^{4n-3}(3n-2)}=\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{17+3\sqrt{33}}}{3}-\dfrac{2}{3\sqrt[3]{17+3\sqrt{33}}}-\dfrac{1}{3}$$

This problem is from [here](http://tieba.baidu.com/p/1569274408?pid=19385944793&cid=#19385944793).

But I consider sometimes,and I think it maybe use Taylor therom

> $$\arcsin{x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n+1)(2n)!!}x^{2n+1}$$

Thank you,Now is 24:00 in beijing time,so I must go bed.I hope someone can help.Thank you

Comment: I can't believe none of the answers below recognized/added that, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\binom{4n-4}{n-1}}{2^{4n-3}(3n-2)}=\frac{1}{T}$$ where $T$ is the ***tribonacci constant***.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The sum can be written as
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{4n}{n}\frac{1}{(3n+1)2^{4n+1}}=\frac{1}{2}{\;}_3F_2 \left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}; \frac{2}{3},\frac{4}{3};\frac{16}{27} \right)$$
For the Hypergeometric Function, see equation (25) of http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html
$${\;}_3F_2 \left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}; \frac{2}{3},\frac{4}{3};y \right) = \frac{1}{1-x^3}$$
where $x$ and $y$ are related by
$$y=\left( \frac{4x(1-x^3)}{3}\sqrt[3]{4} \right)^3$$
Putting $y=16/27$, we get a polynomial equation in $x$.
$$1=16 x^3(1-x^3)^3$$
According to *Mathematica*, this equation has only two real roots which are
$$\begin{align*}
\alpha &= \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}} \\
\beta &= \left\{\frac{1}{6} \left(5-\frac{4}{\left(19-3 \sqrt{33}\right)^{1/3}}-\left(19-3 \sqrt{33}\right)^{1/3}\right) \right\}^{1/3} \end{align*}$$
Numericaly, $\beta$ gives the right answer. So, the final result is
$$ \begin{align*}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{4n}{n}\frac{1}{(3n+1)2^{4n+1}} &=\frac{1}{2\left(1-\beta^3 \right)} \\
&= \dfrac{\sqrt[3]{17+3\sqrt{33}}}{3}-\dfrac{2}{3\sqrt[3]{17+3\sqrt{33}}}-\dfrac{1}{3} \\ &\approx 0.543689\end{align*}$$

Comment: Can you look at this [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2533893/how-do-we-generalize-sum-n-0-infty-binom4nn-frac13n1-24n1)?

Answer (score 21):

The transformed series in Marin's post seems suspiciously like Taylor's expansion of Bring radical
$$\begin{aligned}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\binom{4n-4}{n-1}}{2^{4n-3}(3n-2)} &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{4n}{n} \frac{1}{(3n + 1)2^{4n + 1}} \\ &= \frac{16^{1/3}}{2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{4n}{n} \frac{\left ( 16^{-1/3} \right )^{3n + 1}}{(3n + 1)} \\ &= \frac{1}{2^{1/3}}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(16^{-1/3}\right)^n}{n!} \left [\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}} \left ( 1 + z \right )^{4n} \right ]_{z = 0}\end{aligned}$$

The last sum is the Lagrange-Burmann inversion formula applied to $\phi(z)=(1+z)^4$. It is straightforward now that the series (excluding the constant factor $1/2^{1/3}$) is one of the two real roots of the quartic $z^4 + z + 16^{-1/3}$. One can exclude $-1/2^{1/3}$ via invoking a numerical check, and thus

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\binom{4n-4}{n-1}}{2^{4n-3}(3n-2)} = \dfrac{\sqrt[3]{17+3\sqrt{33}}}{3}-\dfrac{2}{3\sqrt[3]{17+3\sqrt{33}}}-\dfrac{1}{3} \blacksquare$$

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$

> $\ds{%
> {\cal S}
> \equiv
> \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{{4n - 4 \choose n - 1} \over 2^{4n - 3}\,\pars{3n - 2}}
> =
> {1 \over 2}
> \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{4n \choose n}\,{\pars{1/16}^{n} \over 3n + 1}
> =
> {16^{1/3} \over 2}
> \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{4n \choose n}\,{\pars{16^{-1/3}}^{3n + 1} \over 3n + 1}}$.

$$
\mbox{Let's define}\quad
{\rm f}\pars{z}
\equiv
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{4n \choose n}\,{z^{3n + 1} \over 3n + 1}
\quad\mbox{such that}\quad
{\cal S} = {16^{1/3} \over 2}{\rm f}\pars{1 \over 16^{1/3}}
$$

> \begin{align}
> \!\!\!\!{\rm f}'\pars{z}
> &=
> \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}z^{3n}{4n \choose n}
> =
> \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}z^{3n}\int_{\verts{z'}\ =\ 1^{-}}
> {\pars{1 + z'}^{4n} \over z'^{n + 1}}\,{\dd z' \over 2\pi\ic}
> =
> \!\!\!\int_{\verts{z'}\ =\ 1^{-}}\!{\dd z' \over 2\pi\ic}\,{1 \over z'}
> \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{z^{3}\pars{1 + z'}^{4} \over z'}^{n}
> \\[3mm]&=
> \int_{\verts{z'}\ =\ 1^{-}}\!{\dd z' \over 2\pi\ic}
> {1 \over z' - z^{3}\pars{1 + z'}^{4}}
> \end{align}

With WA, we try to find the zeros of $ax^{4} - x + 1 = 0$ $\pars{~a \equiv z^{3}, \quad x \equiv z' + 1~}$ and they [$\underline{\bf look}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ax%5E4+-+x+%2B+1+%3D+0) quite involved. The interesting value of $a$ is $a = z^{3} = 1/16$ and the behavior in $\pars{0,z_{m}}$ with $z_{m} > 16^{-1/3}$. With WA, we look for zeros of $x^{4} -16x + 16 = 0$. It
[$\underline{\bf yields}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4+-+16+x+%2B+16+%3D+0) the following roots, in terms of $z'$:
$$
z' = 1\,,\quad0.0874\,,\quad -2.5437 \pm 2.2303\,\ic
$$
It's clear that there is one root close to zero but ${\bf \mbox{we don't know how  the}\
z' = 1\ \mbox{root evolves when}\ z\ \mbox{moves away of}\ z = 16^{-1/3}}$. The contribution of the root $z_{0}$ "close to zero" is given by:

$$
\lim_{z' \to z_{0}}{z' - z_{0} \over z' - z^{3}\pars{1 + z'}^{4}}
=
{1 \over 1 - 4z^{3}\pars{1 + z_{0}}^{3}}
=
{1 \over 1 - 4z^{3}\pars{z_{0}/z^{3}}^{3/4}}
=
{1 \over 1 - 4z^{3/4}z_{0}^{3/4}}
$$

Notice that $z_{0}$ is a function of $z$. We hope that a precise ( analytical ) solution of the zeros mentioned above will yields ${\rm f}\pars{z}$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: the right side is a root of $27 z^3 + 18 z - 34$.
There is a way to solve equations of the form $x^p + a x + b = 0$ using generalized hypergeometric functions.

Comment: I believe you mean the right side is $x=z-1/3$ where $z$ is the real root of your equation above and $x$ is the reciprocal of the _tribonacci constant_.