# Are there any known infinite series of rational terms that are just irrational (not transcendental)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

I have probably encountered hundreds of infinite series where each term is rational. In each case (as far as I can remember), the value of the infinite series was either rational or transcendental.

For example, some simple cases include:
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^r}&=1\\
\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{r^2}&=\frac{\pi^2}{6}\\
\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{r^2+1}&=\frac{1}{2}(\pi\coth\pi-1).
\end{align}$$
I realize that it's definitely not known that it's true that infinite series of rational terms can only be rational or transcendental, as otherwise we wouldn't say that $\zeta(3)$ and other constants are irrational; we'd immediately be able to say that they are transcendental, so I'm not asking that. I'm asking if anyone knows of any infinite series of rational terms that is *just* irrational, **not** transcendental.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Consider the binomial expansion of $\sqrt{1+x}$ and put $x=1$, say.

Comment: @Tavish isn't the binomial series only valid for $\lvert x\rvert <1$? I see your point though, thank you very much for the simple example.

Comment: Sure, you can take $x=0.5$ for example then. I really was referring to the limit $x\to 1^-$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer provides one infinite series for the number $\sqrt 2$, as well as two infinite series for the famous golden ratio $\phi$.
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{(1-2n)(n!)^24^n}=1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{16}-\frac{5}{126}+...=\sqrt 2.$$

This follows from the power series of $\sqrt{x+1}$. For more infinite series that are equal to $\sqrt 2$, look [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Sqrt/06/).

---

*Series with Fibonacci numbers*

Let $F_n$ denotes the $n$th Fibonacci number. Then
$$\phi=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{F_nF_{n+1}}.$$

*Series with Catalan's number*

Let $C_n$ denote the $n$th Catalan number. Then
$$\phi=\frac{13}{2^3}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}C_{n+1}}{2^{4n+7}}.$$

Comment: Wow...I love the ones involving $\phi$! Thank you!

Comment: For the first series involving $\phi$, do you mean to start the summation at $n=1$?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent Yes of course, I'm sorry for the typo. The series would otherwise not converge because we'd have $F_0=0$ in the denominator. [Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Bsum+from+1+to+100+%28-1%29%5E%28n%2B1%29%2F%28Fibonacci%5Bn%5D*Fibonacci%5Bn%2B1%5D%29) is an approximation for the first $100$ terms of this series for the golden ration.

Comment: I thought so. I really do like that series, I even asked a question about it today :) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4097383/prove-that-sum-k-1-infty-frac-1k1f-kf-k1-frac1-phi?noredirect=1#comment8468765_4097383

Comment: @A-LevelStudent Nice question! I guess one could prove it with the recurrence relation of the Fibonacci numbers. To apologize for my typo ;), here is another series for the golden ratio involving $\pi$ (which converges *very* fast): $$\phi = 2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\pi^{2n}}{25^n(2n)!}$$

Answer (score 7):

$$\sqrt2 = 1 + \frac{4}{10} + \frac{1}{100} + \frac{4}{1000} + \frac{2}{10000} + \frac{1}{100000} + \frac{3}{1000000} +  \cdots$$

In general,
$$\alpha = \lfloor\alpha\rfloor + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\lfloor 10^n \alpha\rfloor - 10 \lfloor 10^{n-1}\alpha\rfloor}{10^n} $$
so *every* real number $\alpha$ -- be it rational, algebraic, or transcendental -- is the sum of some infinite series of rationals.

Comment: This is the best answer I think.+1

Comment: Thank you very much, this answer is great!

Answer (score 2):

The Taylor series expansion of $\sqrt{1+x}$ at $x=1$ is irrational, not transcendental, and each term of the series is rational.

Answer (score 2):

Series
$$
\frac{1}{(4-x)^{1/2}} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{16}x + \frac{3}{156}x^2+\frac{5}{2048}x^3 + \dots
$$
has rational coefficinets and radius of convergence $4$.  Plug in $x=1$
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt3} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{16} + \frac{3}{156}+\frac{5}{2048} + \dots
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$a_n = \lfloor 10^nb\rfloor 10^{-n} $$

Then $a_n$ converges to $b$

Where $b$ is  any irrational number .

From the sequence $a_n$ one can easily create a series (by subtracting of the previous term ).

So $\sum z_{n}$ goes to $b$  ,where $z_n=a_{n+1}-a_{n}$ and all $z_n$ are rational (since all $a_{n}$ are rational)

So taking $b$ to be an irrational number which is not transcendental answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can derive a infinite series of rational terms for any algebraic irrational number using the binomial theorem.

i.e.

$$\sqrt[r]{x}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{ \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{r}\right)}{n! \,\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{r}\right)}\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^n \tag{1}$$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt[r]{x}}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{ \Gamma \left(n-\frac{1}{r}\right)}{n! \,\Gamma \left(-\frac{1}{r}\right)}\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^n\tag{2}$$

both valid for rational $x>1$ and $r>1$

see my previous questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384587/analysis-of-convergence-properties-of-a-series-approximation-to-sqrtx-and?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2535352/rational-series-for-positive-integer-root-of-x1)